# How to check, whether an index is empty in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

In a java application I want to find out, whether my index is empty or not (containing zero documents, or containing at least one documents).

I have the feeling, that counting all documents (by sending a search request with size=0) is not readable and might not be optimal in performance.

Is there a dedicated way for to check, whether an index is empty?

Answer (score 1):

You could do that with the following Java code:

```
IndicesStatsResponse indicesStatsResponse = client().admin().indices().prepareStats(INDEX).get();

indicesStatsResponse.getIndices().get(INDEX).getTotal().docs.getCount());
```

where `client` is  `org.elasticsearch.client.Client` and `INDEX` is the `String`, representing the name of the index.

Interesting is, that some simple test shows, that in average, this request is faster by 20%, than doing `MatchAllDocsQuery`. But I'm not sure if this is a correct test. Maybe I will do a proper one later